# jquery mobile dynamically change content (not the whole page)

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a normal jquery page with header, content and a panel

```html
<div id="myPage" data-role="page">
    <nav id="myPanel" data-role="panel">...menu...</nav>
    <div id="myHeader" data-role="header">...button...text...</div>
    <div id="myContent" data-role="content">...welcome text...</div>
</div>
```

The page is initially loaded with a menu in the panel (with a custom ajax call) and a welcome text as content. Besides text, the header also contains a button to open the menu panel.

When a user taps on a menu item I only want to replace the content, not the entire page.

I've been trying with

```js
$.mobile.changePage('my/valid/url', {
    pageContainer : $('#myPage')
});
```

I can see in my network log that I get the correct content from the JQM ajax call. But  when I look at the DOM, the only thing that happened is that an empty `div` is appended to `#myPage`, i.e. the content from ajax is not inserted. And the old content is still there. See below:

```html
<div id="myPage" data-role="page">
    <nav id="myPanel" data-role="panel">...menu...</nav>
    <div id="myHeader" data-role="header">...button...text...</div>
    <div id="myContent" data-role="content">...welcome text...</div>
    <div data-role="content" data-url="my/valid/url">EMPTY</div>
</div>
```

One other thing is that the whole page, `#myPage`, is hidden `(display="none")`. It seems that JQM wants to show an entire new page instead of just allowing me to change the content of one div inside `#myPage`.

**Is it possible to change just a part of a JQM-page using JQM?**

I've done it with a custom ajax call and then appended the markup to the DOM myself. But then I need to do a lot of other stuff manually, like enhancing , showing/hiding the load indicator etc.

Comment: can't you just use jq to replace the content of that page with the new content?

Comment: I can do it myself with ajax but I want to use JQM, like $.mobile.changePage or similar.

Comment: this is what you want http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/mdcS7/